# Julia Array of arrays: (rows -> columns) performance

Tags: arrays, julia

Complete Julia newbie here.

Given an array of arrays, I want to combine corresponding elements of each sub-array. Something like this:

```
 [2, 7, 9]       [2, 3, 2, 7, 3]
 [3, 5, 4]       [7, 5, 7, 9, 5]
 [2, 7, 7]  ->   [9, 4, 7, 1, 1]
 [7, 9, 1]
 [3, 5, 1]
```

Searching stackoverflow I came across a couple of solutions other than a direct loop or a list comprehension.

```
julia> a=Vector{Int}[rand(1:10,3) for i=1:5]
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 7, 9]
 [3, 5, 4]
 [2, 7, 7]
 [7, 9, 1]
 [3, 5, 1]

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime a2=mapslices( x -> [x], hcat(a...), dims=2)[:]
  6.174 μs (65 allocations: 3.45 KiB)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 3, 2, 7, 3]
 [7, 5, 7, 9, 5]
 [9, 4, 7, 1, 1]

julia> @btime a3=[getindex.(a,i) for i=1:length(a[1])]
  948.087 ns (14 allocations: 768 bytes)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 3, 2, 7, 3]
 [7, 5, 7, 9, 5]
 [9, 4, 7, 1, 1]
```

My question is: Why is the second one about six times faster than the first one? Does it have to do with hcat?

Comment: If you want a third better one take this: `julia> @btime a3 = [[a[i] for a in $a] for i = 1:3]
  193.593 ns (9 allocations: 640 bytes)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 3, 2, 7, 3]
 [7, 5, 7, 9, 5]
 [9, 4, 7, 1, 1]`. It all comes down to allocations, first example `(65 allocations: 3.45 KiB)`, second `(14 allocations: 768 bytes)`, and mine `(9 allocations: 640 bytes)`. In Julia code, it is best to avoid any unnecessary allocations for maximum speed.

Comment: No, this is just a benchmarking artefact. You are interpolating `a` into the benchmarking expression, while @toylas didn't. If you interpolate correctly they have similar performance. I would rather suggest this, though: `[getindex.(a,i) for i in eachindex(first(a))]`, on my laptop that's 10% faster, but more importantly, it's more robust (though you should still ).  BTW, I don't think it's a good idea to write `[a[i] for a in a]`, it's highly confusing to reuse `a` as the iteration variable, in fact I'm a bit surprised it even works.

Comment: Note on original timings in question, It is a problem to benchmark on non-const globals. You should either interpolate them in by writing `$a` instead of `a` like how @aboammar is, or make it const. I have seen this lead to misleading results that can even flip the order of different alternatives being considered because the resulting break of type inference dominates. I have not checked if this is one such case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Baseline and Benchmarking correctly

Ok, first lets establish the baseline on my computer.

Before we do anything else we need to make sure we are not benchmarking on global variables.
From the [BenchmarkTools readme](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl#quick-start):

> If the expression you want to benchmark depends on external variables, you should use [`$` to "interpolate"](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions) them into the benchmark expression to [avoid the problems of benchmarking with globals](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1).
>   Essentially, any interpolated variable `$x` or expression `$(...)` is "pre-computed" before benchmarking begins...

```
julia> a=Vector{Int}[rand(1:10,3) for i=1:5];

julia> @btime a2=mapslices( x -> [x], hcat($a...), dims=2)[:];
  6.015 μs (65 allocations: 3.45 KiB)

julia> @btime a3=[getindex.($a,i) for i=1:length($a[1])];
  149.228 ns (6 allocations: 544 bytes)
```

(If i didn't interpolate, I would get the same as you roughly for `a3` `999.500 ns (14 allocations: 768 bytes)`).

So it is `a3` is not 6 times faster, but actually 33 times faster.

## Why the difference?

### Allocations.

Allocations are fairly slow compared to other operations (in all languages).
We can see that the `a2` code allocates much more than the `a3` code.

So lets look at the bits that allocate:

#### `a2`

- `[x]` allocates a new 1-element array for each column
- `hcat` allocates a new matrix with everything concatenated
- `mapslices` allocates an array for each slice it takes out of the matrix
- `mapslice` allocate an array to hold the output (interesting that it does not do a view, but i checked)
- `[:]` performs a reshaped copy of the output. (alternative would be `vec` which returns a reshapes view)

#### `a3`

- `getindex.(a, i)` allocates an array for each column of the output (so same as `mapslice` internal slicing of the input matrix)
- `[ ... for ...]` allocates an array for the output (so same as mapslices output)

  So we can see that there are a bunch of extra allocations going on in `a2` that are not in `a3`.

  #### What if we only had the allocations assoicated with the `hcat`.

  Since the original question asks if it is because of the `hcat` lets look at that.

I define a new benchmark saving into `a4`.
It uses [`eachslice`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachslice) which returns a (lazy) generator of views into slices of the matrix. So negligible allocations there.
To stop it being lazy we `collect` it.
The final output of this is an `Array` of `SubArray`s (rather than an `Array` of `Arrays`) but that is fine, it will work just as it still subtypes `AbstractArray`.

```
julia> @btime a4 = collect(eachslice(hcat($a...), dims=1));
  734.320 ns (13 allocations: 704 bytes)
```

Here our major allocations are the 
 - `hcat`
 - `collect` which allocates the output (same as `[ ... for ...]`).

So yes, the `hcat` has an effect, but it is far from the majority of the difference.

### Splatting and `reduce(hcat, xs)`

Splatting as a cost. Its generally pretty small until you get up to splatting hundreds of items, but because this is a microbenchmark and everthing else is so fast lets see how it goes to remove it.

Julia has an optimized function for `reduce(hcat, xs)` for `xs` being an array of arrays.

so lets see how that goes:

```
julia> @btime a2_s=mapslices(x -> [x], reduce(hcat, $a), dims=2);
  5.278 μs (59 allocations: 3.17 KiB)

julia> @btime a4_s=collect(eachslice(reduce(hcat, $a), dims=1));
  337.656 ns (8 allocations: 528 bytes)
```

We can see that is it makes a difference.
But in the case of `a2` it's not much, since the `hcat` is done once, where as the slow allocations in `x->x` and in `mapslices` copying slices out of the `hcat` happens many times.

## Can we go faster?

Not really.
`a3` is pretty much the ideal code for this.
It allocates nothing that it does not return.

Thought if we are willing to swap over to using [StaticArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl)
we can get something truly unreasonably fast.

```
julia> b = @SVector [@SVector [rand(1:10) for ii in 1:3] for i=1:5];

julia> @btime b3=[getindex.($b,i) for i in 1:length($b[1])];
  36.055 ns (1 allocation: 208 bytes)
```

Static arrays gives the compiler a bunch more information.
In particular the size of all the arrays, and the promise that none of them will ever be changed.
This means it can:
 - unroll loops
 - bounds check at compile time
 - allocate them on the stack (rather than the heap)
 - probably some other things I have forgotten.

This lets the optimizer (both in Julia and in LLVM) go really wild.
The wold them gets compiled down to basically 2 SSE/AVX vectorized move operations per input column (/output row), plus a small amount of fixed overhead.

```
julia> @code_native (b->[getindex.(b,i) for i in 1:length(b[1])])(b)
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
; ┌ @ REPL[83]:1 within `#161'
    subq    $136, %rsp
    vmovups (%rdi), %ymm0
    vmovups 32(%rdi), %ymm1
    vmovups 64(%rdi), %ymm2
    vmovups 88(%rdi), %ymm3
    vmovups %ymm3, 88(%rsp)
    vmovups %ymm2, 64(%rsp)
    vmovups %ymm1, 32(%rsp)
    vmovups %ymm0, (%rsp)
    movabsq $5152370032, %rax       ## imm = 0x1331AED70
; │┌ @ generator.jl:32 within `Generator' @ generator.jl:32
    vmovaps (%rax), %xmm0
    vmovups %xmm0, 120(%rsp)
; │└
    movabsq $collect, %rax
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    vzeroupper
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $136, %rsp
    retq
    nop
; └
```

Comment: It seems it can go a bit faster if one writes out the loops with `@inbounds`, but it's like 10% difference on v1.4.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but wasn't sure that it was a meaningful difference. Also given we are deciding the inner length using just the length of the first, and assuming it is the same for the others, it wasn't something that seemed particularly safe. It takes away the guard rail from mistakes in earlier code.

Comment: I used the shortest array length in the code, but anyway the performance benefit was slight.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in such detail. Things do make sense to me now.